# MSVC 2019 and 2022 compiler hangs and is erratic compiling relatively large std::complex arrays in c++17 and c++20

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Using the latest C++ MSVC 2019 and 2022 the following code hangs while compiling

```
#include <complex>
// const int N = 10000; // about 3 secs
// const int N = 40000; // about 40 secs
const int N = 200000; // hangs (over 10 min)
//const int N = 2000000; // normal, 1 sec
std::complex<double> x[N];
int main()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 200; i++)
        x[i] = std::complex<double>(1,2);
}
```

Oddly, it compiles, at different speeds as shown including much larger sizes. Looks like a bug and I have reported it. Works fine if in a vector with the same sizes. Any idea what is causing this. Concern is that this may pop up elsewhere or produce bad compilations.

Comment: In fact! I was able to reproduce on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/T386n71ca) what you describe. Very strange... Wouldn't it be worth to be reported to Microsoft directly?

Comment: At a guess it's trying to do something in memory but you don't have enough free memory, making the array larger over some threshold makes it not attempt to do whatever it's doing in memory or to do something different which uses less memory. Do you really need larger static arrays? Could you not use `std::vector` instead which would avoid the need for compile time processing

Comment: @AlanBirtles I have 24gb of ram. When looking at ram usage during the hang, VC is using 3.2gb. So not a shortage of user ram. And the weird fact that increasing the size makes it compile quickly.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat thanks. Looks like a bug. I'll report it.

Answer (score -1):

Move the variable inside main and you`ll see a fast compile; but don't panic if it crashes while debugging.
Currently you have declared a huge static object and the compiler is most probably trying to allocate disk space for it. Assess the size of final generated binary (.exe file). It should be about 10xN. you may find compile optimization switches that sacrifice execution speed in favor of memory or executable size.
Now this big file is not alone. There a bunch of steps before generation of final binary that - thanks to you - deal with some more gigantic files, including the object (.obj) file. This simple (?) program is taking up gigabytes of your storage.

Edit:==============================

After a certain threshold - which I guess can be tuned with a compiler switch - the compiler resorts to dynamically allocating memory for the huge static object; from the programmer's perspective however, that is still a static object.
Anyhow, such huge objects should not be placed on static storage, nor on automatic storage. They must be placed on dynamic store; either via a `std::vector` or via a `std::unique_ptr` or some other smart object:

```
std::vector<std::complex<double> >bigvec{bigN,0.0};
auto bigptr=std::make_unique<complex<double>[]>(bigN);
```

Because in the end(one way or another), huge objects will impose run-time overhead for initialization. I can't imagine how the OS is supposed to load and run a GB executable; That just creeps me.

Comment: Your explanation sounds reasonable in general but fails to explain why it works fine on OPs side with even bigger arrays. (Not to mention that I was able to reproduce the exact behavior described by OP on Compiler-Explorer.)

Comment: Obvious: when the threshold is met, compiler resorts to dynamic allocation. From the programmer`s view, it is still static but no more suitable for compiletime allocation.

Comment: Obvious or not... Your comment is the more reasonable explanation and should be part of your answer. I fiddled again with the sample on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/f3d67x3Ea). Comparing the generated code for lesser and larger  array, there is in fact a `dynamic initializer for 'x'` in the latter.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat What is missing next?!